# how to use a Map in a controller?

Tags: visualforce, controller, map

I am trying to do a shopping cart functionality.  I was able to do it using a list.  But the problem is the cart are getting duplicates if the user adds or modifies the cart.  I tried converting the list into a map but I am getting errors.

How do I convert the list into a Map to check for duplicates?

[image: vf controller]

[image: VF Page]

Comment: Are you trying to just prevent duplicates from your list? If so why not go for a set than a map. Changing your List<DisplayMerchandise> to set<DisplayMerchandise> should get rid of the dupes

Comment: @rao yes, just trying to prevent duplicates in the shopping cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `List<DisplayMerchandise> to Set<DisplayMerchandise>` in your line 2 in the controller class, this should get rid of the dupes.

**Update:**

One way I would do is add the set you created to a list and then sort the list and return the list. (please test this not too sure if this would work, I tried with a list and it did not sure if sort will work for non primitive types)

declare this :

List list_withnodupes = new List();

before return products;

```
list_withnodupes.addall(products);
list_withnodupes.sort();
return list_withnodupes ;
```

**Update 2:**
If you wish to follow the map route I have a small example here :

Page:

```
<apex:page Controller="account_vals">
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!accvals}" var="acc">
<apex:column value="{!accvals[acc].name}" headervalue="name"/>
</apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class account_vals {
set<string> acc_set{get;set;}
List<account> acc_List{get;set;}
public map<string,account> account_map{get;set;}
public account_vals(){
    acc_set = new set<string>();
    acc_List = new list<account>();
    account_map = new map<string,account>();
}

public map<string,account> getaccvals(){
    acc_List = [select id,name from account limit 20];
    for(account a: acc_List){
        if(!account_map.containsKey(a.name)){
            account_map.put(a.name,a);
        }
    }
return account_map;
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: the set is working, no more duplicates.  But I am wondering what if I want to retain the order of products by id? Because now every time I click on the Add To Card button the cart gets randomized.  Thanks.

Comment: You could use the sorting implementation for your DisplayMerchandise class. Check the documentation at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_comparable.htm#apex_comparable

Comment: @DavidSchach the minute he adds it back into a set there is no guarantee that the order will be maintained.

Comment: Yes. So use the Set, put it into a List, sort that List, and return the List.

Comment: :) thats what I recommended, but if I was not sure if custom list ie List<displaymechandise> can be sorted using List.sort() method. I thought only default types like string,sobjects were sortable

Comment: It can be sorted.  In that case the DisplayMerchandise class would have to implement the [Comparable interface](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_comparable.htm).